# Configuration of masks in PixelCNN

Tags: cnn

I have trouble understanding the masks in PixelCNN [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06759).

[image] [image]

Here for A, each channel is connected to prior channels. For B, channels are also connected to themselves. My problem is in first layer when I go from 3 channels to number of filters. Let's say I have 128 filters, how is the mask then implemented? What I implemented so far with the assumption that there is same number of channels in each layer is:

```
H = KERNEL_SIZE[0]
W = KERNEL_SIZE[1]
N = OUT_CHANNEL
M = IN_CHANNEL

# implement context mask
mask = np.zeros((N, M, H, W))
mask[:,:,:(H//2)] = 1
mask[:,:,(H//2),range((W//2))] = 1

# implement channel mask
if mask_type == 'A':
    mask[np.triu_indices(N, k=0, m=M)] = 0
elif mask_type == 'B':
    mask[np.triu_indices(N, k=1, m=M)] = 0
```